# Show only chapter number (and not name) as chapter heading?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

The chapters in the book I'm working on are all named. However, while I want the names to show up in the TOC, I want the numbers and the numbers only to show up as the chapter headings. (I know that sounds weird, and I'll be happy to explain why if it matters.)

So, for example, the name of chapter I is "De Puero Superstite." I want "De Puero Superstite" to show up in the TOC, but only the number I to show up as the chapter heading. (I've already got it set to Roman numerals.)

Is there a way to do this? If I need to I can use `titlesec` to redefine the title format, leave the numbers out entirely, and do eg `\chapter[De Puero Superstite]{I}`, but there's got to be a more elegant way to do it.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** By "Chapter Heading" I mean not the page header—the thing that appears at, for example, the very top of every left page (or every right page, or every page) but the thing that appears once before the text of the chapter begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want the ToC entry to appear in the page headers or not. For the ToC entry and page header entries to be the same.

```
% chapternameprob.tex  SE 544473 no name in division header
%\documentclass{memoir}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{} % eliminate Chapter in divisional heading
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[toc and header entry]{} % empty divisional title
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

For them to be different use the `memoir` class:

```
% chapternameprob.tex  SE 544473 no name in division header
\documentclass{memoir}
%\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[toc entry][header entry]{}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The `memoir` class enables you to have different entries in the ToC, the page header, and the main document for all the divisional commands (`\chapter` ... `\subparagraph`)

Comment: Thank you! This works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch} % for \xpatchcmd
\usepackage{lipsum} % for \lipsum to produce dummy texts 

\makeatletter
% hide chapter title (e.g., "first title")
\xpatchcmd\ttl@mkchap
  {\ttl@mkchap@i{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}}
  {\ttl@mkchap@i{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{}}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

% hide \chaptername (the word "Chapter" followed by a space)
% based on `texdoc titlesec`, sec. 9.2
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  % before: {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
  {\thechapter}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{first title}
\lipsum

\chapter{second title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hunh. A MWE of your code gives me "1," which I want, followed by "first title," which I don't. Have I missed something? Sorry not to understand.

Comment: @JoelDerfner Do you copy-and-paste my whole example, or just use add the redefinition of `\chaptermark` into your existing document?

Comment: I did a new LaTeX file, copied and pasted just your code into it, and compiled it. It gave me "1 first title."

Comment: @JoelDerfner Which latex distribution and which version of that distribution are you using? Does the compiling results in any errors? The output is ok both on my side (texlive 2020) and on overleaf.com (texlive 2019).

Comment: That is really, really weird, because I'm using texlive 2019 on overleaf! I took a screen shot to show you but I can't seem to add it to a comment. (In case it matters, I'm using pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: (And your code compiles with no errors.)

Comment: @JoelDerfner Overleaf has a share-by-link utility. So you can paste the link to that overleaf project here.

Comment: @JoelDerfner Ah I mis-understood your question. You want to show only "I." and "II." in text area, I provided an example showing "I" and  "II" on header area (the header in "header and footer"). Give me some time and I will prepare a right example. PS: you can safely delete the comment containing links to overleaf.

Comment: AH! I'm so sorry for not being clear! I really appreciate your sticking with this—if only everybody in the world were as patient as you!

Comment: @JoelDerfner Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I'll edit the question to make it clearer, wait a few days just in case, and then accept!